# How to compare elements of an array with string in hive

Tags: arrays, hadoop, hive

I have created an table with complex data type `array` in hive. The query is

```
create table testivr (
     mobNo string,
     callTime string,
     refNo int,
     callCat string,
     menus array <string>,
     endType string,
     duration int,
     transferNode string
     )
row format delimited 
fields terminated by ','
collection items terminated by '|'
```

The records loaded are like

> 9220276765 2011-05-01 21:26:45 29  E   ["PRE_HOST10_JINGLE_PP-PREF_WELCOME_PP-PREF_PROMO_PP","M001:4","M477:3","M005:2","M090:5","M465:9"] RAT 218 TR716

Now I need to check whether the first two fields of array are:

`PRE_HOST10_JINGLE_PPPREF_WELCOME_PP-PREF_PROMO_PP` and `M001`.

I tried using:

```
select * where menu[0] = "val1" and menu[1] = "val2"`
```

and also like

```
menu(0) = "val1" and menu(1) = "val2"
```

I'm getting an error like:

> SemanticException [Error 10011]: Line 3:0 Invalid function 'menus'

How to compare them?

Comment: can you show some sample table data and the full query used?

Comment: Your error doesn't match the query. And you stopped using square brackets because why?

Answer (score 0):

if the val1 and val2 are hardcoded value
val1 = "PRE_HOST10_JINGLE_PPPREF_WELCOME_PP-PREF_PROMO_PP"
val2 = 'M001'
you may try to convert array to string and use substr to find expect value

```
--sample records
with testivr as (
  select '9220276765' as mobNo
  , '2011-05-01 21:26:45' as callTime
  , 29 as refNo
  , 'E' as callCat
  , array("PRE_HOST10_JINGLE_PP-PREF_WELCOME_PP-PREF_PROMO_PP","M001:4","M477:3","M005:2","M090:5","M465:9") as menus
  , 'RAT' as endType
  , 218 as duration
  , 'TR716' as transferNode
  
  union all 
  
  select '9220276766'
  , '2011-05-02 21:26:45'
  , 30
  , 'E'
  , array("PRE_HOST10_JINGLE_PP-PREF_WELCOME_PP-PREF_PROMO_PP","M001:5","M478:4","M006:3","M091:5","M465:10")
  , 'RAT'
  , 219
  , 'TR717'
  
  union all 
  
  select '9220276767'
  , '2011-05-03 21:26:45'
  , 31
  , 'E'
  , array("PRE_HOST10_JINGLE_PP-PREF_WELCOME_PP-PREF_PROMO_PP","M002:5","M478:4","M006:3","M091:5","M465:10")
  , 'RAT'
  , 220
  , 'TR718'
)

select mobno,refno,menus
from testivr t
where substr(concat_ws(',',menus),1,50) = 'PRE_HOST10_JINGLE_PP-PREF_WELCOME_PP-PREF_PROMO_PP'
  and substr(concat_ws(',',menus),52,4) = 'M001'
;
```

Temp Table testivr:

```
+-------------+----------------------+----------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-------------+-----------------+--+
|   t.mobno   |      t.calltime      | t.refno  | t.callcat  |                                                t.menus                                                | t.endtype  | t.duration  | t.transfernode  |
+-------------+----------------------+----------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-------------+-----------------+--+
| 9220276765  | 2011-05-01 21:26:45  | 29       | E          | ["PRE_HOST10_JINGLE_PP-PREF_WELCOME_PP-PREF_PROMO_PP","M001:4","M477:3","M005:2","M090:5","M465:9"]   | RAT        | 218         | TR716           |
| 9220276766  | 2011-05-02 21:26:45  | 30       | E          | ["PRE_HOST10_JINGLE_PP-PREF_WELCOME_PP-PREF_PROMO_PP","M001:5","M478:4","M006:3","M091:5","M465:10"]  | RAT        | 219         | TR717           |
| 9220276767  | 2011-05-03 21:26:45  | 31       | E          | ["PRE_HOST10_JINGLE_PP-PREF_WELCOME_PP-PREF_PROMO_PP","M002:5","M478:4","M006:3","M091:5","M465:10"]  | RAT        | 220         | TR718           |
+-------------+----------------------+----------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-------------+-----------------+--+
```

Query results:

```
+-------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
|    mobno    | refno  |                                                 menus                                                 |
+-------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
| 9220276765  | 29     | ["PRE_HOST10_JINGLE_PP-PREF_WELCOME_PP-PREF_PROMO_PP","M001:4","M477:3","M005:2","M090:5","M465:9"]   |
| 9220276766  | 30     | ["PRE_HOST10_JINGLE_PP-PREF_WELCOME_PP-PREF_PROMO_PP","M001:5","M478:4","M006:3","M091:5","M465:10"]  |
+-------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
```